# XAMPP Laravel Permission denied macOS Monterey

Tags: php, laravel, macos, xampp

I'm encountering an unexpected issue while working with XAMPP and Laravel on macOS Monterey. Every time I try to access my Laravel application, I'm getting the following error:

"UnexpectedValueException
The stream or file "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ezonlinetools.com/components/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened in append mode: Failed to open stream: Permission denied
"

This error is preventing me from accessing my Laravel application properly. Additionally, attempts to log files also result in permission denied errors.

Updated the Apache httpd.conf file to allow for virtual hosts and configured it to recognize my Laravel application's domain name ([www.ezonlinetools.com](http://www.ezonlinetools.com)).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZnhx.png)

In attempts to resolve the permission denied issue on my Laravel application hosted on XAMPP in macOS Monterey, I made several changes and troubleshooting efforts.

Comment: *"I made several changes and troubleshooting efforts"* - Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78156117/edit) and show these attempts. Permission Denied is a pretty ambiguous error, but it's pretty clear that the `laravel.log` file, or the folder it's in, has the incorrect permissions (or ownership). You can also check other existing questions, like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639174/how-to-set-up-file-permissions-for-laravel to see if they can solve your issues too.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable input and suggestions. let me explore the linked question and similar resources to see if they can offer solutions to my specific issue.

Comment: I've successfully resolved the problem by moving my project out of the /Applications directory. It turns out that writing directly into system folders like this one can cause permission issues. thanks @etresoft from https://discussions.apple.com/thread/255529611